# How to check if an Enum is used in Java

Tags: java, enums

I was wondering if there is a way of finding out which enums are used. I've got a list full of objects an need to check which of my enums is used and which isn't used.

I tried to iterate through the list and got all Objects back which used an Enum but I don't know how to get the unused ones.

Comment: If you found all enums that are used, then the ones that aren't used are just the ones remaining, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`EnumSet#allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf-java.lang.Class-) to get all the values in the enum, and remove the used ones from it:

```
EnumSet<MyEnum> all = EnumSet.allOf(MyEnum.class);
for (MyObject obj : allOfTheObjects) {
    all.remove(obj.getEnumMember());
}

// Whatever remains in "all" are the unused enum values
```